# Confusion about connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

A metric space is said to be "connected" it there is no subset that is both closed and open.

Sets are open if "any sufficiently tiny ball around a point is fully contained" and "closed" if their complement is open.

What I don't understand is why the union of two disjoint closed sets isn't connected?

Like in the Cartesian plane, why aren't the union of the unit closed disks centered at (0,1) and (10,10) "connected"?

I can't think of a subset that is both open and closed.

Comment: Each of the two disks is both open and closed.  You describe each as closed, which means the other is open (as it is the complement of a closed set).

Comment: I thought openness was defined as "any sufficiently small region around any point in the set is fully contained in the set." And that "closed" was defined as the complement of open. Wouldn't your definition of "open" be circular?

Comment: To add to the above comment, note that the closed balls will not be open in the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$, but they will be open in the new space which is the union of the two balls.

Comment: @aman If a closed set by definition is a complement of an open set, then it follows that a set is open if and only if its complement is closed. It's not a new definition of an open set, it is a simple lemma. (the proof is pretty much trivial)

Comment: Ok wait, I think I understand the issue. "Connectedness" is defined with respect to a metric space. All points within a small ball drawn around a point on the perimeter of the closed ball that are *within* the new metric space are still within the set that is the first ball.

Comment: @Mark my point was that cannot be how the terms are defined but anyway I think I got it now.

Comment: @aman Yes, you got it. What lulu meant was that there are equivalent definitions of a closed set, and in general, you can check directly that a closed ball is closed, without checking that its complement is open. (many times this is easier by the way) But if you have only the definition right now, then yes, you have to check that both balls are open in the new space. You understood correctly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The two closed disks as a subspace of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the subspace topology. Openness in the subspace is defined in a different way: Either disk is open in the subspace topology